# How does the Galois group of a splitting field act on a specific element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Let $charK \neq 2$, $L/K$ be the splitting field of a separable polynomial $f \in K[x]$.
Further let $a_1,...,a_n \in L$ be the roots of $f$.

1. How does the Galoisgroup $Gal(L/K)$ act on $c:=\prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}(a_i-a_j)$?
2. $Fix Gal(L/K) \cap A_n =K(c)$

My attempt:

About 1):

As far as I know for $\sigma \in Gal(L/K)$ we have that $\sigma$ permutates the roots $a_1,...,a_n$. Now (by intuition) I would say that

$\sigma(\prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}(a_i-a_j))=\prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}(\sigma(a_i)-\sigma(a_j))=sgn(\sigma) \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}(a_i-a_j)$

But I am not really sure how to answer the question in Nr.1.

About 2):

I know that $Gal(L/K)$ should be a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$.
$A_n$ denotes the even permutations, and $A_n \leq S_n $. If $\sigma \ in Fix Gal(L/K) \cap A_n$, then we have that $\sigma(c)=c$

My only approach would be to use the teorem about the primitive element:

Let L be s field extension of the form $L=K(a,c_1,...,c_n)$ such that $a$ is algebraic over $K$ and $c_1,...,c_n$ are separable over $K$, then there exists a primitive element $b \in L $ such that $L=K(b)$.

But since this theorem only says something about the existence, I don't think that it would be useful.

Comment: Your first part is a [Van der Monde determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix#Determinant), which formalises your first point with a transposition swapping rows.

Comment: @George I do see that the Van der Monde determinant has some connection to the question asked. Because I am a little bit unsure, the wiki article just states an argument for my (intuitive) calculation $\sigma(c)=sgn(\sigma)c$ right? (Because I don't see more than that.) I think I didn't express myself correct. On the question "How does $Gal(L/K)$" act on $c$, my answer would be "it fixes $c$, with exception to the sign". In part 1, my problem is more of a "How do I formulate this"-problem. Nevertheless, thank you very much for the hint with the Van der Monde determinant.

Comment: @wanymose Where you able to make progress on this exercise?

Comment: @Walli unfortunately no

Comment: Note that for a separable polynomial $f \in K[x]$ (degree of $f$ is $n$) where $\text{char}(K) \neq 2$, the Galois group of the polynomial $\text{Gal}(f)$ can be imbedded into $A_n$ iff the discriminant of $f$, which is equal to $c^2$, is a square in $K$. Perhaps this will help.